# Did Voldemort die or stay in limbo after the final battle?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows,* while Harry is in Kings Cross he sees something like a small child, which is the fragment of Voldemort's soul that was attached to him.

> He recoiled. He had spotted the thing that was making the noise. It had
>   the form of a small, naked child, curled on the ground, its skin raw and rough, flayed-looking, and it lay shuddering under a seat where it had been left, unwanted, stuffed out of sight, struggling for breath.
>
> He was afraid of it. Small and fragile and wounded though it was, he did not want to approach it. Nevertheless he drew slowly nearer, ready to jump back at any moment. Soon he stood near enough to touch it, yet he could not bring himself to do it. He felt like a coward. He ought to comfort it, but it repulsed him.
>
> *Harry Potter and The Deathly Hallows*

Once Harry returns to the world of the living, that part of Voldemort's soul stays in limbo. Is this what happens to all fragments of someone's soul if he has divided his soul by creating a Horcrux? Does that mean that Voldemort's soul however crippled will stay in limbo or when all parts of his soul die, so does he?

Comment: Is the question asking if all the other soul fragments have their own separate existences in Limbo?

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive, with a direct quote from JKR to address your question. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum well, I had read that before as well, but I've always assumed it referred to the part of Voldemort's soul that inhibited Harry. If that form was one part of his soul, what about the rest?

Comment: @System - That is the last part of his soul. The other parts apparently dissipated when their host (the horcruxes) were destroyed.

Comment: @Valorum so the part that is with Harry at King's Cross dissipated & but the main part of Voldemort's soul that resided inside him remained on King's Cross?

Comment: @system - Kings Cross is merely a representation of Limbo, not a literal place

Comment: @Valorum - There were two fragments of V's soul still in the mortal realm: The one that was still in his body, and the one employed for making Nagini into a Horcrux.  What Harry perceived in the antechamber of death (assuming it corresponded to something real) was one or more of the other pieces, clinging together but incomplete.

Comment: As I understand it, in King’s Cross there are two souls: Harry’s (complete and undamaged) and Voldemort’s (what remains of it in his regenerated body). That’s why Voldemort, in the real world, is unconscious during the King’s Cross events. The Horcrux parts of Voldemort’s soul aren’t present, having either been already destroyed (including the one that user to be in Harry) or being still bound to their container (Nagini).

Answer (score 18):

JKR stated in an [interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html) that after Voldemort's death at the Battle of Hogwarts, he was forced to remain in his "stunted" form in Limbo, presumably for all eternity.

> **Jon:** *Since Voldemort was afraid of death, did he choose to be a ghost if so where does he haunt or is this not possible due to his
>   Horcruxes?*
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** *No, he is not a ghost. He is forced to exist in the stunted form we witnessed in King's Cross.*