# Would having Horcruxes allow someone to leave the Veil of Death?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

In the Harry Potter books, there is a veil of death in the Department of Mysteries. It got me thinking about the Horcruxes and for some odd reason i started to speculate about Horcruxes and how the veil could be related. So my question is: Were Horcruxes created so that a living being could anchor themselves to the living world if that being were to go through the veil and allow that being to come back through again without any trouble? Meaning if you were to travel through the veil and you had created a Horcrux before doing so and left that soul piece in the living world, would you be able to travel back out of the veil and into the living world, where your soul was tied to?

Answer (score 8):

## It’s unclear if having a Horcrux would let someone leave the veil.

There isn’t much knowledge about how exactly the veil works, so it’s impossible to say for sure what would happen to someone with a Horcrux who falls through the veil.

- It’s possible that if someone with a Horcrux falls through the veil, their *body* would fall through the veil, but their disembodied soul would be able to leave but be reduced to a spirit-state like the Dark Lord existed in after killing the Potters.
- It’s *also* possible that the veil works as a barrier, and even if someone had a Horcrux, their “master piece of soul” would have fallen through the veil and be unable to escape.

There’s one possibility that seems fairly safe to eliminate. It seems very unlikely that having a Horcrux would allow someone to exit the veil with their soul still in their body. Horcruxes don’t protect the body from things that would kill it, they just tether the soul to life so that it would remain earthbound and not “move on” with the death of the body. As we see when the Dark Lord is hit by the rebounding Killing Curse, it doesn’t preserve the body.

Answer (score 3):

We have a very limited amount of information about the Veil.

As the books never mention Sirius' funeral and Harry attends a wizarding funeral for the first time when Dumbledore dies, we can assume that no one ever found Sirius' body.

The magic of the Veil seems extremely ancient and enigmatic, as it is an object kept under close scrutiny for more than 200 years and no one has apparently ever understood it fully.

Voldemort certainly knows nothing about it, despite being an extremely powerful wizard. He is, after all, scared of death and - as Dumbledore repeatedly says -ignorant of many branches of magic. He has most likely never studied a way to get out of the Veil, and inventing counter-charms probably requires a strong understanding of the magic that you're trying to undo.

Therefore, we can assume that **no human body could ever leave the Veil regardless of Horcruxes**. It would get stuck there forever or vanish "into non-being".

We don't know whether the Veil affects the soul and, if so, how.

One possibility is that Voldemort's soul would remain tied to Voldemort's body, forced to lie beyond the Veil.

Another, perhaps more interesting, possibility is that the Veil acts somewhat like a permanent Limbo and, thus, that Voldemort would stay there

> [forced to exist in the stunted form we witnessed in King's Cross](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/130017/60559).