# What was the skeleton under bench in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 2

Tags: harry-potter

Spoilers for Deathly Hallows

> When Voldemort killed Harry and went to the train station,

who or what was the skeleton under the white bench?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/130014/did-voldemort-die-or-stay-in-limbo-after-the-final-battle here buddy this may answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

That skeletal creature is the physical manifestation of Voldemort's soul; marred after having been ripped apart so many times. This is the form he will be forced to remain in forever. This is probably what Dumbledore referred to when he told Voldemort that there are things far worse than death when he fought him in *Order of the Phoenix*